# Syslog-ng can close connection

Tags: tcp, syslog, timeout

I have a server that collect secure/auth logs in my datacenter from all other server, it runs syslog-ng 3.2.5. It's configured to receive tcp connection, here is the conf:

`tcp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514) max-connections(200));`

Configured like this I have 200 clients and 200 tcp connection on port 514 always active, but there are some clients that dont write anything for days. Is it possible to configure syslog-ng to close tcp connection after inactivity from clients?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, syslog-ng will automatically close the connections after a period of inactivity, unless the so_keepalive() option is enabled in the source (the server) or the destination (the client).

If you still see activity in the connections, try to set the mark_freq() option to 0.